# How to interpolate between the physical, material universe with relativistic reference frames and a spiritual objective reference frame?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, communication, faster-than-light

I'm new here and I assume that it might be weird to have souls in a science-fiction question but hear me out. While souls in my setting do have some magical unexplainable supernatural properties, it isn't what I want to ask here, this question is about the physical consequences of some properties I'm giving this set up.

**The Soul Field:**

I created this field for souls to connect to or reside in, it is an objective reference frame field, where time always ticks at the same rate and space is compressed to a single point. Regular physics do not work there, of course.
The Soul Field can gradually transition to regular space-time in the material universe, where physics should be realistic, dictated by relativity and so on.
All points in this gradient would map to the slices above and below in order to keep the smoothness, meaning that eventually all points in the universe map to the same, single point of the Soul Field.
I decided that the clock rate of the Soul Field should be similar to the CMB frame, since it is the backdrop of the entire universe.

If I'm not missing something, the Soul Field is instantaneously accessible anywhere in the universe, and from an information perspective, the universe would appear to shrink as it climbs the gradient, allowing for messages to travel faster and faster until they become instantaneous at the Soul Field.

**Telepathy:**

Due to the requirements of my setting, I need communication between souls to be possible, even if one is in the afterlife and the other isn't.
In the Soul Field this is trivial, since relativity does not apply there, and since all points are the same.
But anywhere closer to the material universe, I expect problems due to general and special relativity making souls perceive time at different rates.
The way I tried to fix this was by having the souls move up the gradient, closer to the Soul Field, and send the message in that way, minimizing the effects of both relativities and allowing for faster communication (interpolating between lightspeed and instantaneous depending on how close to the Soul Field they are).

The problem is that my brain is getting stuck thinking about how that would look like for living beings, trying to shift their frame of reference to align with the Soul Field (CMB frame), but without really changing how they move from the outside (this would be bad).
One restriction that I already have is that two souls that are in the material universe cannot shift to eachother's perspective directly, in order to obtain maximum alignment they must both be as close to the Soul Field as possible. They can only adjust between their own frame of reference and the Soul Field, knowing that the Soul Field is the same for everyone.

What is the best way to interpolate between a given relativistic frame of reference and an OBJECTIVE frame of reference?
And at the risk of breaking the rules: Is there a better way of doing this? (ignore this if I shouldn't be asking it in the same question).

Comment: What does the word "interpolate" mean? It obviously cannot have its usual meaning in a question which contains no numbers or functions with numeric values. (And in world where there exists an objective reference frame Einsteinian relativity, special or general, doesn't apply anyway; the entire point of Einstein's theories of relativity is that there is **no** objective reference frame.)

Comment: Interpolating the reference frames, if that makes any sense at all. In a way I imagine it must, since that is what happens naturally when you boost yourself between reference frames in regular relativity.
And yes, I know that regular relativity does not apply. In this universe relativity is just an approximation. This is why there is a gradient between the objective reference frame and the regular relativistic way things work. I just don't want to be lazy and use magic hand waving to explain why I have black holes and time dilation but also FTL souls.

Comment: what is your current process like? for when someone is attempting to use telepathy.

Comment: I was imagining that someone would have to sit there in distorted time as they shift their reference frame closer to the Soul Field, if needed. Basically the rate of time would change to match what is needed for the universal time rate in the Soul Field. I'm not sure how this would work and look like, though. Living individuals right next to one another would not have to bother since they are already in reference frames that are virtually identical.

Comment: Not weird at all ... so don't apologise!

Comment: The idea of souls and "higher planes" of existence crop up a *ton* in sci-fi. I can't think of many sci-fi novels I've read where it doesn't, in one form or another.

Answer (score 1):

I think a half-baked idea I was having the other day might apply here.

In relativity, there is no absolute reference frame. If there was a clock at every point in space they would all read differently. But presumably, the clocks were all wound at the same time: the "Big Bang". I think you could justify that the soul field is the "place" before the big bang, where only time existed (space hadn't expanded yet). So, running on this assumption that you could read the clock at your point in space, you would know your temporal distance to the singularity. That's your objective reference frame.

I suggest that travel between the soul singularity and our material universe happens in discrete "jumps". Once you know your distance from relativity-governed space to the singularity, you can perform an instantaneous jump to it, and vice versa, from the singularity back to any point in space at its "latest" clock date. I could be wrong about this, but I *believe* this avoids causality paradoxes associated with FTL--almost. I know you'll need one additional stop-gap<sup>1</sup>.
You can think of the universe as a kind of bar graph, I guess, where the time on each clock at each point is mapped to the height of a bar in the graph. You can only move between/exist at the very bottom of each bar (the singularity) or the tippy-tops.

[image: bar graph space-time]
<sub><sup>(Important to note, the "bars" all converge at the singularity, which is by definition just a point.)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> I believe this also means the universe is a 4-torus; souls from the far, far future can wrap back to the singularity (by hopping off the "bar graph"), influencing the future (from the distant past). That stop-gap I mentioned will have to exist at the transition from singularity to our universe with spatial dimensions. Souls at the singularity *can't know* how space comes to exist, or else they can create causality paradoxes in the usual fashion.

<sub>Essentially, the acts of souls at the singularity are responsible for the way the universe shapes out, but souls can't know *how* their actions contribute to the state of the universe just after the singularity.</sub></sub>

I think part of what you're asking isn't very feasible. You want a smooth gradual transition from a 1-dimensional "place" of only time to a 4-dimensional place of time and space. I'm not sure you can gradually transition like that. A line can bifurcate and the space between them can become a 2d "universe", and later on, that 2d surface can split to get a 3d volume, but there's always a discrete point where the transition happens.

I don't think the idea of a spaceless line of "time" really jives with the idea of instantaneous communication. Ignoring everything I said and going off your Q, as you recede from relativity-space and head for the soul field, the universe wouldn't shrink but instead grow, as communication becomes faster and more regions of the universe become accessible. Eventually, the entire universe is accessible. This would be my singularity. From the singularity, communication anywhere in the universe could be done (again, only communication to the "tippy-tops" of the universe--the in-betweens are inaccessible). Furthermore, down at the soul field/singularity, there wouldn't be any "time". Information can pass around instantly. Every soul *ever* would form a kind of geometric construction without space/time dimension.
(And it's kind of poetic, in a way. Every soul that would ever exist burst from the singularity, traveled through space-time, and fell back to the singularity. And every soul is indirectly involved in how the universe takes shape.)
<sub><sup>What came first? The universe or the soul?</sup></sub>

Anyway, if you want your souls to interact with the universe at the same speed as the universe (at the "speed of time"), ... well, you've already got it. They can only jump to the "tippy-tops", which means they experience time all the same, all the while existing in a dimensionless amalgamation.

Comment: Thanks for this input, I really like the universal time-keeping thing, but I got confused at the bar graph and I also fail to see why it can't be a smooth gradient. My Soul Field can't be timeless because I need souls to experience time there, which should help prevent paradoxes. I also wanted to require them to be on the same "level" to communicate at first, but that causes issues that did not cross my mind, so now I also have to solve for messages going up and down the gradient. Finally the Soul Field would be away from blackholes, as it's supposed to have time with zero curvature.

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy from your comment I realize my message didn't fully come through. The bar graph is important for understanding the idea. Each "bar" is a point in relativistic space-time. Each bar's height is the time that has elapsed since the Bing Bang. Near black holes, where curvature and time dilation is great, time elapsed less, so the bars are closer to the singularity, while places like our solar system that aren't under extreme time dilation, the bars are higher--more time has elapsed for us that for anyone in the vicinity of black holes.

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy Secondly, souls at the "singularity" aren't timeless. Even though they *exist* in that dimensionless amalgamation, they "share" our time dimension, the universe's time dimension. (This is because they can only jump to the "tippy-tops" of the "bars", which are constantly moving forward in time.)

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy let me know if this clarifies anything for you.

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy Also, you can't have a smooth gradient between a 1-dimensional manifold and a 4-dimensional manifold. It just isn't mathematically possible (without introducing infinite compacted distances, I think...). There are going to be sharp points and edges.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, but I'm still confused. There is a singularity where time since the big bang is like "true time", and in the material universe it is dilated time due to relativity. The jump can only be between true time and the dilated time for a given position. Somtimes it sounds like time shouldn't flow in the singularity, though, since you only mentioned the clocks for normal spacetime and said the singularity is the place before the big-bang. Again, I really need the Soul Field to be the opposite of a blackhole, time dilation is at a minimum in the Soul Field.

Comment: On this line of thought, they would be jumping between the bigbang and the "present"... which sounds a bit wrong, since it would mean that ALL presents connect to the same point (the singularity), meaning that all presents are connected, meaning time travel. The only way I see out of this is to give the singularity a clock of its own as well, that has a bar separated from the bigbang. Obviously I also failed to understand the stopgap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129688/discussion-between-pedrohspacewolfy-and-bmf).

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy I'm sorry, chat does not work on the SE mobile app. My concept is not a perfect fit for your idea. The "stop gap" is some kind of line in the sand that prevents causality paradoxes. It prevents souls from jumping from relativistic time (the tops of the "bar graph" analogy) to the singularity, and changing conditions in the singularity to affect changes to the entire universe. It does this by scrambling the information needed to understand how the singularity transitions into the real universe (via the Big Bang).

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy You're also right that all "presents" (all the tops of the bar graph analogy) are connected (via travel to the singularity). But I'm not sure if this creates time travel problems. You can only move on that surface (a 3d surface describing the relativistic "present"). I don't think you can plot a course that takes you into your own past this way. I intend on exploring the idea further, maybe asking a question myself about it later.

Comment: Oh sorry, the site told me to do it. And yeah, there are quite a few things about your solution that do not match what I need. Right now forced time dilation seems to be my best bet, but I still don't know what that would look to the body (which is another problem with your thing, since sharp jumps would mean the physical body experiences singularity time). I guess I should try going into the equations myself to see if messing with time can compensate for differences in inertial reference frames. I'm sure this will screw me up thermodynamically at some point, but it might be the only way.

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy you need the "soul field" to not be "a black hole", but I'm not sure what you mean by that. At the same time, you describe it as being compressed to a single point. All the while, it experiences time. That sounds to me like either a 1-dimensional "universe" with only a time dimension (no space, looks a lot like a 1-d line), or a single point without dimension.

Comment: @PedrohSpaceWolfy measuring your distance to the big bang singularity is probably your best bet for finding an "objective" reference frame that everyone in the universe can agree on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the scientific understanding to answer your question in the physics jargon in which you've asked it.  For example, at my IQ-level, "Frame of Reference" refers to the cultural and philosophical biases which a person might bring into a situation. It's a characteristic of the person experiencing the universe rather than an aspect of that universe itself.

But I've listened to enough of the big brains around here to know that you are indeed using your words correctly, despite the fact that I don't personally understand them.

What I do understand is that you are trying to facilitate a situation-limited communication between souls whether they are incarnate within the physical, material universe or existing elsewhere with a soul field. To that question, let me offer a scientifically ignorant but perhaps useful solution...

Instead of defining your incarnate material world brain as a soul cage in which a former occupant of the soul field resides while incarnate down here, make the brain a transceiver through which the soul field occupant interacts with our world. Then make the experience of using the transceiver more than fully immersive.  Make it so captivating that the soul's full attention is so enthralled by the idea of three physical dimensions and one-directional time, that it totally forgets its higher existence. For as long as that brain continues to perceive our world the way we see it, our distant yet enraptured soul cannot look away.

With this understanding, the process of communicating with other souls on the soul field requires that you escape from the mesmerizing effects of our reality through meditation, drugs, deep-sleep or fervent prayer. Only when your soul distances itself from three-dimensionality does it remember how to communicate with its brethren.

Communicating with other incarnate souls is handled in the same way, but both enthralled souls need to meditate themselves out of enrapture at the same time.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but there are few things in this answer that do not work for me specifically. I need relativity to be in the universe, and with that comes the problems I am trying to solve. In this solution I still need to address the shear in time perception between souls or between the material universe and the Soul Field. By having the soul at the Soul Field it goes back to the very problem I am trying to solve, what that difference would look like, between the soul at the Soul Field and the body at the material universe. Points in between would just be that but weaker.